# Android Things on tablet

Tags: android, tablet, android-things

Is it possible to use *Android Things* on a tablet? 
My project needs *Android Things*, but I can't use *Raspberry* for it, because it will be expensive.

If not, what do I do to a "normal" *Android* (*Android* for tablets/phones) to have only my application, don't have notification bar and don't close my app with the life cycle? (like on *Android Things*)

Comment: "It's possible to use Android things on a tablet?" -- if you are the manufacturer of the tablet, presumably this is possible. If you have experience in creating custom ROMs, and there is a custom Android ROM for the tablet, you might be able to create a custom Things ROM.

Comment: You can also use [COSU](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html) mode for "normal" Android (Android for tablets/phones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's possible to use Android things on a tablet?

No. Here is the [list of supported platforms](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html#hardware_platforms).

> If not, what do I do to the "normal Android".

Develop a [kiosk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android%20kiosk-mode?mode=all) app or, if it's not enough for you, [customize *Android* source code](https://source.android.com/).

Comment: It's possible to have only my app, run the app on boot load and remove the notification bar with kiosk? (remove him, not hide)

Comment: Here are a [kiosk-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kiosk-mode/info) tag info and the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android%20kiosk-mode?mode=all)

Comment: _"It's possible to have only my app, run the app on boot load..."_ Not quite - the system UI app will still be there. Consider a kiosk mode app to be a "pretender" for the only app in the system. If you want full control over the system learn [AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-source)